# Triggering the submithandler with jQuery

Tags: jquery, triggers, submit, handler, form-submit

I'm trying to trigger the submithandler in jQuery, but it goes to the action page when submitting. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$('#target').submit(function() {
    alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
    return false;
});
</script>
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
    <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="other">
    Trigger the handler
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#target').submit(function() {
      alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
      return false;
  });
});
</script>
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
    <input type="text" value="Hello there" />
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<div id="other">
    Trigger the handler
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two changes... one, wrap your code in an `onready`, and two, add a `preventDefault`:

```
$(function() {
  $('#target').submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert('Handler for .submit() called.');
      return false;
  });
});
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: I believe `return false;` does the same thing as `event.preventDefault();`. I prefer using `event.preventDefault()` over `return false;`.

Comment: Ah, right you are - I was thinking normal (non-jQuery) event handlers.